# using something like group_concat on clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to get a result of

| types | name |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | banana, apple, guaba, strawberry |

from a table with database like

table: fruits

| types | name |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | banana |
| fruit | apple |
| fruit | guaba |
| fruit | strawberry |

I know with MySQL I can use group_concat to get the result I want by using

```
SELECT group_concat(name), types FROM fruits
```

I have done my research and people recommend me to use groupArray in clickhouse to obtain similar result but this is not what I want. Because when I use

```
SELECT groupArray(name), types FROM fruits GROUP BY types
```

it gives me result of

| types | name |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | apple, banana, banana, strawberry,strawberry,strawberry, guaba,guaba,guaba,guaba |

the order of groupArray is mixed up and I can't seem to find an answer to fix the order :(

is there any way in clickhouse where we can get array of results in order? and why are there duplicated results?

I can't use groupUniqArray because sometimes my result should be

banana, apple, guaba, strawberry, strawberry (if strawberry is there twice in DB)

how do I keep the duplicated data without having it multiplied in order???

- I have data of input_time and key so my table is something like

| types | name | input_time | key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | banana | 01:01 | 01 |
| fruit | apple | 01:02 | 01 |
| fruit | guaba | 01:03 | 02 |
| fruit | strawberry | 01:04 | 03 |
| fruit | strawberry | 01:05 | 04 |

and forgetting about 'types', I want to get result of grouped names in DB saved order (input_time order) group by key. How should I change my query??

I've tried

`SELECT groupArray(name), key FROM fruits GROUP BY key ORDER BY input_time`

but it does not give me the result I want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use order by in sub-query. The order in the array is the same as the order of rows at a previous stage of query pipeline

```sql
select types, arrayCompact(groupArray(name))  names, length(names) len from(
   select types, name from fruit order by types, input_time)
group by types


┌─types─┬─names───────────────────────────────────┬─len─┐
│ fruit │ ['banana','apple','guaba','strawberry'] │   4 │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────┘
```

*https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arraycompact
Removes consecutive duplicate elements from an array. The order of result values is determined by the order in the source array.*

Comment: thank you! It helped me a lot! I want to ask one more question if its okay, is there any function I can use to count the number of array ? I tried countSubstrings() function but somehow its undefined function in my clickhouse (maybe because of the version problem)

Comment: I asked this because I want to count how mane names are there in arrayCompact. I was trying to count the numbers of , +1 to get the number but do you think there would be any better way to count the numbers of names in array?

Comment: I've added ` length(names) `

Comment: Depending on context/use-case, groupUniqArray(name) may be functionally equivalent to arrayCompact(groupArray(name))